# Evolution of Temperature in Time and Space in an Infinite Bar

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature

[image: Uniform bar]

> An infinitely long, uniform bar is **perfectly insulated** and one end
> is kept at a constant temperature ($T_s$). How does its temperature
> evolve in time and space?

Because the bar's cross-section is negligible W.R.T. its length, we can treat this as a quasi-$\text{1D}$ problem and Fourier's equation applies. We're looking for a function $T(x,t)$ that satisfies:

$$\partial_t T=\alpha \partial_{xx} T$$

and any boundary/initial conditions.

In addition we assume the bar's initial ($t=0$) temperature is $T_i$.

My question is inspired by this [PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623557/transient-heating-of-semi-infinite-solid-time-it-takes-for-given-depth-to-reac). It was initially framed for a constant heat flux $\mathbf{q}$ at $x=0$ but somewhat later the OP seems to have settled for the simpler case I presented above.

For a bar of **finite length** $L$ this becomes a fairly banal BVP (a second BC was used where the heat conduction at $x=L$ is $0$) with initial condition, and with solution of the form:

$$\boxed{T(x,t)=T_s+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n\exp\Big({-\alpha \Big(\frac{\pi n }{2L}\Big)^2 t}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{\pi n x}{2L}\Big)}$$
For $n=1,2,3,...$
Determine the coefficients $B_n$ with the Fourier series:
$$B_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^LT_i\cos\Big(\frac{\pi n x}{2L}\Big)\mathrm{d}x$$

For a very long bar, i.e. $L\to \infty$, this tends to the question the OP asked.

At one point he then declared in the comments that he'd found the answer to his question on a page titled '**2.2. Transient Conduction in Semi-Infinite Slab**' (find the link provided by G.Smith in the comments). It's a very poor quality resource that posits the solution without any derivation whatsoever as being:

$$\boxed{\frac{T(x,t)-T_s}{T_i-T_s}=\mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\alpha t}}\Big)}$$

This looks like an extremely neat solution to a complex problem (at least to me) and I haven't the slightest idea how it was arrived at or whether it is even correct. The equation is dimensionally consistent, always a good sign of course.

On way forward could be to compare the solution for the the finite bar and the web page's solution for ever increasing values of $L$ and see if they converge. But that seems like an awful amount of work.

So my question really is: '**does anyone have a(n) idea(s) on how to tackle the $L=\infty$ problem?**'

[This page](https://www.cdeep.iitb.ac.in/webpage_data/nptel/Mechanical/Heat%20and%20Mass%20Transfer/Conduction/Module%204/main/4.5.html#:%7E:text=TRANSIENT%20HEAT%20CONDUCTION%20IN%20SEMI%2DINFINITE%20SOLIDS&text=A%20semi%2Dinfinite%20solid%20is,directions%2C%20as%20shown%20in%20Fig.&text=For%20a%20finite%20heat%20transfer,the%20time%20t%20approaches%20infinity.) does confirm the validity of the $\mathrm{erf}$ solution.

Comment: To check the answer, just substitute it into the differential equation and BCs, and see if it satisfies them.  This is a so-called similarity solution or boundary layer solution applicable to a case in which there is no identifiable length scale.  The way of solving a problem like this is to start with de-dimensionalizing the differential equation and BCs, to there point that there is a length scale that can be cancelled by combining two of the dimensionless independent variables into a single similarity variable.  See Bird et al, Transport Phenomena.

Comment: Ah. The LHS and the group $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\alpha t}}$ are indeed dimensionless groups.

Comment: You’ve linked to a file on a C drive.

Comment: @G.Smith Thanks! There seems to be no way to link this as a web page. I've provided the full title, so it will be easy to Google.

Comment: Are you talking about [this PDF](https://community.ptc.com/sejnu66972/attachments/sejnu66972/PTCMathcad/176513/1/2.2_Transient_Conduction_in_Semi-Infinite_Slab.pdf)?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, that is the page I wanted to link to. But your link too immediately downloads the page as a *.pdf, at least on my tooter.

Comment: I see. On my iPad it just displays the PDF.

Comment: @G.Smith I'll refer to your link in my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

With thanks to 'Chet' in the comments it appears this problem (at least without convection) isn't really hard.

$$\partial_t T=\alpha \partial_{xx}T$$
Boundary conditions:
$$T(x,0)=T_i$$

$$T(0,t)=T_s$$

Introduce a Similarity Variable $\eta$:

$$\eta=\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\alpha t}}$$
This transforms the original PDE into an ODE:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2T(\eta)}{\mathrm{d}\eta^2}=-2\eta \frac{\mathrm{d}T(\eta)}{\mathrm{d}\eta}\tag{1}$$
Transform also the boundary conditions:
$$T(x,0)=T_i\to T(\eta\to \infty)=T_i$$
$$T(0,t)=T_s\to T(\eta=0)=T_s$$
This then solves to:
$$\frac{T(x,t)-T_s}{T_i-T_s}=\mathrm{erf}(\eta)$$
$$\boxed{\frac{T(x,t)-T_s}{T_i-T_s}=\mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\alpha t}}\Big)}$$

---

Solving $(1)$ -

Substitute $z=T'(\eta)$ and $z'=T''(\eta)$, so that:

$$z'=-2\eta z$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z}=-2\eta$$
$$\ln z=-\eta^2+c$$
$$z=c_1\exp{(-\eta^2)}$$
$$T'(\eta)=c_1\exp{(-\eta^2)}$$
Integrate again:
$$T(\eta)=c_1\int \exp{(-\eta^2)}+c_2$$

Apply the BC and IV to determine $c_1$ and $c_2$.