# Transient temperature profile of an infinite rod with conduction and convection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

[image: Uniform rod]

An infinitely long and uniform bar is clamped at one end ($x=0$). The surrounding temperature is $T_{\infty}$ and Newtonian convection takes place. At $t=0$ the temperature at $x=0$ is suddenly increased to $T_s$. If the initial temperature was $T_i$ (for $x\to \infty$) then what is the temperature evolution in time over $x$?

---

Firstly we must set up an equation, involving Fourier's law of heat conduction and Newton's law of cooling, by means of the heat balance of an element $\Delta x$. We assume no temperature gradients in the $y$ and $z$ directions.

[image: Heat balance of rod]

The convective heat loss of the element is given by:

$$- p\Delta xh(T(x)-T_{\infty})$$

($p$ is the perimeter of the bar, for a slab e.g. $p$ = 2 $\times$ width + 2 $\times$ thickness)

The heat balance of that segment now is:

$$A\rho c_p \Delta x \frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}=Aφ(x)-Aφ(x+\Delta x)- p\Delta xh(T-T_{\infty})$$

where $A$ is the bar's cross-section.

Divide both sides by $A\Delta x$ and rearrange slightly:

$$\rho c_p\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}=-\frac{φ(x+\Delta x)-φ(x)}{\Delta x}- \frac{ph}{A}(T-T_{\infty})$$

Now take the limit of both sides to get derivatives:

$$\rho c_p \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta T}{\Delta t}=-\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{φ(x+\Delta x)-φ(x)}{\Delta x}- \frac{ph}{A}(T-T_{\infty})$$
$$\rho c_p\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial φ}{\partial x}- \frac{ph}{A}(T-T_{\infty})$$
Now get rid of the flux $φ$ with Fourier's law of heat conduction:
$$φ(x)=-k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$$
So that:
$$c_p\rho \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=k\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial x^2}- \frac{ph}{A}(T-T_{\infty})$$
Now with:
$$\alpha=\frac{k}{c_p\rho}$$
Then in PDE shorthand:
$$\boxed{T_t=\alpha T_{xx}-\frac{ph}{\rho c_p A}(T-T_{\infty})}$$
For simplicity's sake:
$$\frac{ph}{\rho c_p A}=c$$
$$T_t=\alpha T_{xx}-c(T-T_{\infty})\tag{1}$$
$$T(0,t)=T_s\text{ and } T(x,0)=T_i\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ we look for the steady state solution: $T_t=0$:
$$\alpha T''(x)-c[T(x)-T_{\infty}]=0$$
$$y=T-T_{\infty}$$
$$y''(x)-\frac{c}{\alpha}y(x)=0$$
$$m^2=\frac{c}{\alpha}$$
$$y''-m^2y=0$$
$$y=c_1e^{mx}+c_2e^{-mx}$$
So that:
$$T(x)=T_{\infty}+c_1e^{mx}+c_2e^{-mx}$$
BC:
$$T(0)=T_s$$
$$T_s=T_{\infty}+c_1+c_2$$
It's obvious that unless:
$$c_1=0$$
then $T\to \infty$ for $x\to\infty$, so $c_1=0$. Thus:
$$T_s=T_{\infty}+c_2$$
$$c_2=T_s-T_{\infty}$$
$$T_E(x)=T_{\infty}+(T_s-T_{\infty})e^{-mx}$$

---

There must now by virtue of the Superposition Principle exist a function $u(x,t)$, so that:

$$T(x,t)=T_E+u(x,t)$$
$$T_t(x,t)=0+u_t(x,t)$$
$$T_{xx}(x,t)=m^2(T_s-T_{\infty})e^{-mx}+u_{xx}(x,t)$$
The BC of $(2)$ transforms to:
$$u(0,t)=T_s-[T_{\infty}+(T_s-T_{\infty})]=0$$
With:
$$\boxed{u_t=\alpha u_{xx}}$$
Which is homogeneous.

And that'd how far I've gotten...

Comment: You had kind-of the right idea.  But, instead, first solve for the final steady state temperature profile at infinite time.  Then represent u(x,t) as T(x,t) minus the final steady state temperature profile.

Comment: @ChetMiller That occurred to me too but  $\alpha T_{xx}-c(T-T_{\infty})=0$ requires two BCs in $x$ and we've only got one?

Comment: The BC at infinity is $T\rightarrow T_{\infty}$

Comment: @ChetMiller   How do we know that for certain?

Comment: That is the temperature of the entire rod before we change the temperature at x = 0.  After all the heat entering at x = 0 is gradually drawn out along the rod by the convection to the surroundings, there is nothing left to heat up the part of the rod at large x.  The length scale over which this occurs is going to be on the order of $\sqrt{\alpha/c}$

Comment: But the initial temperature is $T(x,0)=T_i(x\to\infty))$, not $T_{\infty}$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122541/discussion-between-chet-miller-and-gert).

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623955/evolution-of-temperature-in-time-and-space-in-an-infinite-bar/623974#623974) can be gleaned that the solution to the last PDE is:

$$\frac{u(x,t)-T_s}{T_i-T_s}=\mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\alpha t}}\Big)$$

Or:

$$u(x,t)=T_s+(T_i-T_s)\mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\alpha t}}\Big)$$

Superposed with the Steady State function we get:

$$\boxed{T(x,t)=T_{\infty}+(T_s-T_{\infty})e^{-mx}+T_s+(T_i-T_s)\mathrm{erf}\Big(\frac{x}{2\sqrt{\alpha t}}\Big)}$$

where $m^2=c/\alpha$.