# Analytical solution of the thermal conductivity equation

Tags: thermodynamics, computational-physics, simulations, error-analysis, thermal-conductivity

What is the exact analytical solution of a 1D thermal conductivity PDE:

$\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha\cdot \dfrac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$,

where $T$ = temperature, $\alpha$ = thermal conductivity coefficient, $x\in\left(0,\ldots,L\right)$ = distance coordinate,  $t$ = time.

with mixed **B.C.**

- ***Dirichlet type B.C.***: $\:\:T\left(x=0, t\right)\:=\: 30$
- ***Neumann type B.C.***: $\:\:\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x} \left(x=L, t\right)\:=\: 0$

I would like to implement the analytical solution into my code to compare an error of numerical schemes I used to numerically solve this eq. I have found that this equation has a numerical solution, but only as an information, not the solution itself.

Comment: You can find this discussed [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/heateqni.pdf), for example, as well as in nearly any heat transfer textbook or handbook.

Comment: There is no one single analytic solution.  The solutions to this equation vary with the imposed boundary conditions and initial conditions.

Comment: @ChetMiller Thanks, I think that I came by some source saying that. I also read that the geometry may play certain role (however, not in case of a 1D heat transfer without radial gradients, I assumed). I have updated my post with the I.C. and B.C..

Comment: @Chemomechanics, I will look into the paper, thanks.

Comment: The term initial condition refers to the specified temperature profile at time zero.

Comment: @ChetMiller Yes, corrected :) I considered the right condition in my code, just rewrite it badly to the post.

Comment: This q&A https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623955/evolution-of-temperature-in-time-and-space-in-an-infinite-bar/623974#623974 is an example of what you're looking for.

Comment: @Gert However, my boundary condition is different. Referring to "@ChetMiller", for some types of B.C., the equation does not have a solution. I am not sure whether I can get $c_1$ and $c_2$, but I will try.

Comment: @JoshE. You have only one (homogeneous) BC. That can't be solved as a Boundary Value Problem (BVP). You'll probably need to use Similarity Variable (as I had to). A PDE isn't just a PDE: together with any IC or BC it becomes a *system* of equations.

Comment: What is the BC at $x=0$?

Comment: @JoshE. If you really need a solution specific to your problem math.SE is probably your best bet.

Comment: @JoshE.    *What is the BC at x=0?* In my case? $T(0,t)=T_s$. The BC isn't really the problem. But you have only $1$ BC in $x$ for a PDE that is second order in $x$!

Comment: @Gert I looked once again at my code and I don't have any I.C., just two B.C. as it is corrected in the post, sorry.

Comment: @jacob1729 Corrected in the post.

Comment: @JoshE. What you call "**I.C.**" is not an initial condition, it's a boundary condition (BC). So in PDE shorthand you have $T(0,t)=30$ and $T_x(L,t)=0$.

Comment: I don't mind solving this for you (tomorrow) but you need to be **sure** of your BCs. And you need a IC as well, e.g. $T(x,0)=f(x)$

Comment: @JoshE. So would you like me to post the derivation and analytical solution tomorrow?

Comment: @Gert Yes, I would appreciate it a lot! Thanks. As for the I.C., I really don't use one - the temperature is described by the main PDE function I would say, such that $T\left(x,0\right) = f(x)$ as you mentioned. Yesterday, I also found this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322509964_Analytical_and_numerical_solution_of_the_heat_conduction_problem_in_the_rod), but the B.C. is different and I am not able to use it in my code for the comparison.

Comment: @Gert This [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342495390_Analytical_Solution_of_Homogeneous_One-Dimensional_Heat_Equation_with_Neumann_Boundary_Conditions) on the other hand, used Neumann B.C. only - the analytical solution eq. (16) differs from the previous [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322509964_Analytical_and_numerical_solution_of_the_heat_conduction_problem_in_the_rod), also eq. (16) a bit, hence mine case would be different as well.

Comment: @JoshE. It's the Real World problem that **imposes** the BCs and IC, they're not of your choice. The IC is needed to determine the coefficients of the Fourier expansion. No IC, no dice (except for a Steady State solution. '@Roger' below didn't use your BCs.

Comment: @Gert Yes, another typo, thanks. The condition is correct as you wrote it. Actually, I sticked to these conditions (BCs and IC), because for these, I had a comparison in the form of graph, when I was making a numerical solution. Hence, I did not apply the equation on a real problem yet.

Comment: OK, all good. I just simplified the use of the variable $n$ a bit. But works also as stated before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our partial differential equation (PDE) and boundary conditions (BCs) are:
$$T_t=\alpha T_{xx};$$
$$T(0,t)=30\text{ and }T_x(L,t)=0.$$
Let's use a generic initial condition (IC):
$$T(x,0)=f(x).$$
First, we transform the dependent variable $T(x,t)$:
$$u(x,t)=T(x,t)-30.$$
This means that:
$$\Rightarrow u(0,t)=30-30=0.$$
The derivative $T_x(L,t)$ isn't affected, so:
$$u_x(L,t)=T_x(L,t)=0.$$
Calculate the derivatives:
$$u_t=T_t\text{ and }T_{xx}=u_{xx}.$$
So we've transformed our PDE to:
$$u_t=\alpha u_{xx};$$
$$u(0,t)=0\text{ and }u_x(L,t)=0;$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)-30.$$

---

Now the solving process starts. We use *separation of variables*.

Assume (make an *Ansatz*) that:
$$u(x,t)=X(x)\Theta(t),$$
where $X(x)$ and $\Theta(t)$ are functions in $x$ and $t$ only, respectively. Insert into the PDE:
$$X\Theta'=\alpha\Theta X''.$$
Divide both sides by $XT$ to get:
$$\frac{\Theta'}{\alpha \Theta}=\frac{X''}{X}=-k^2,$$
where $k^2\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k^2>0$, called the *separation constant*.
The PDE is now 'broken up' into two ordinary differential equations (ODEs):
$$\frac{\Theta'}{\alpha \Theta}=-k^2\tag{1};$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}=-k^2\tag{2}.$$
Let's start with the second one. Its solution process is:
$$X(x)=A\sin kx+B\cos kx;$$
$$u(0,t)=0\Rightarrow X(x)=0;$$
$$0=A\sin 0+B\cos 0\Rightarrow B=0;$$
$$X(x)=A\sin kx;$$
$$u_x(L,t)=0\Rightarrow X'(L)=0;$$
$$0=kA\cos kL\Rightarrow \cos kL=0;$$
$$\Rightarrow k=\frac{(n+1/2)\pi}{L};$$
$$k=\frac{(1+2n)\pi}{2L}.$$
The $k$ terms are the *eigenvalues* of the PDE.
So we have:

$$X_n(x)=A_n\sin\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi x}{2L}\right).$$
for $n=0,1,2,3,...$

---

From $(1)$, we glean easily that:

$$\Theta_n(t)=\exp{(-\alpha k^2t)}=\exp{\left[-\alpha\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi}{2L}\right)^2t\right]};$$
Thus:
$$u_n(x,t)=A_n\exp{\left[-\alpha\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi}{2L}\right)^2t\right]}\sin\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi x}{2L}\right).$$
With the *superposition principle*, we get:

$$\boxed{u(x,t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n\exp{\left[-\alpha\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi}{2L}\right)^2t\right]}\sin\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi x}{2L}\right)}$$
for $n=0,1,2,3,...$

At $t=0$, we have:
$$f(x)-30=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi x}{2L}\right).$$
We can then use the Fourier series to determine the coefficients $A_n$:

$$\boxed{A_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L\mathrm{d}x\left[\big(f(x)-30\big)\sin\left(\frac{(1+2n)\pi x}{2L}\right)\right].}$$
Finally, don't forget that $T(x,t)=u(x,t)+30$.

Comment: Awesome, it works, the code nicely plots the curve. Finally, I have a nice comparison, thanks. Thanks for writing it in words of one syllable, I highly appreciate it.

Comment: Great! I'm now going to make a small simplification.

Comment: I've simplified the use of $n$ a little.

Comment: I edited what seemed to be some typos involving $n$. Please check, and I apologize if I've introduced any errors into this fine answer.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The general solution for $$\partial_t T(x,t)=\alpha\Delta T(x,t) \,\,\,\text{with}\,\,\, T(0,t)=T(L,t)=0$$ is $$u(x,t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k e^{-\alpha\lambda_kt}f_k(x),$$ where the functions $f_k$ are eigenfunctions of the La-Place-Operator to the eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ $$\Delta f_k=\lambda_k f_k,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ with boundary conditions $f_k(0,t)=f_k(L,t)=0$. Because this implies $$\partial_t u(x,t)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k (-\alpha\lambda_k)e^{-\alpha\lambda_kt}f_k(x)\stackrel{(1)}{=}-\alpha\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}a_k e^{-\lambda_kt}\Delta f_k(x)=-\alpha\Delta u(x,t)$$ and $$u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0.$$

The eigenvalue problem (1) is easy to solve with the exponential function: $$f_k(x)=C\sin(k\pi x/L)\,\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\,\lambda_k=-\left(\frac{k\pi}{L}\right)^2.$$ The constant $C$ is defined by the inicial condition $T(x,0)$, after plugged in in $u(x,t)$.

For other boundary conditions add linear terms in $x$ to $u(x,t)$, as it will still solve the PDE. For example $$v(x,t)=u(x,t)+30$$ solves your Dirichlet B.C.. For more difficult B.C., solve the eigenvalue problem with according boundary conditions.

Comment: What does $u'(x,t)=u(x,t)+30$ mean? Looks like abuse of notation to me.

Comment: @Gert as it says explicitly in my answer: I used $u(x,t)$ for the solution with boundary conditions $u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0$ and $u'(x,t)$ for the solution with boundary conditions $u'(0,t)=u'(L,t)=30$.

Comment: So $u'(x,t)$ is *u prime*? If so, it's clearer to use $v(x,t)=u(x,t)+30$, IMHO...

Comment: @Gert depends on the notation you use. I don't think the prime notation is misleading, as this is the physics stack exchange and the prime notation for derivatives is more of a mathematical one. Nevertheless I will change my notation then.

Comment: I use (e.g.) $y'$ here all the time (also $\dot{y}$ and others). There's no convention that tells us what notation to use *here* or *there*.

Comment: @Gert Thats exactly my point.